# Angular2 - Allow the service call only when valid email id has been entered

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

In my angular 2 app, I have a child component which is a modal with email, confirm Email field, Send and Cancel button.When I enter some invalid email lets say Henry in email field and confirm email field,the service call does not happen as its an invalid input.But when I try to give some valid email id, I want the service call to happen i.e the child component should emit the data to parent to make the service call.Its a small modal with Send and Cancel button where I am making a service call on click of the send button to send an email. I want the service call to happen only when valid email is entered. I am  not using any form-group here to check if email is valid or not.I am only using Javascript regEx to validate email expression.

my HTML-

```
 <md-input placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" name=""></md-input>
 <md-input placeholder="Confirm Email" [(ngModel)]="confirmEmail"name="">
</md-input>
<button (click)="sendEmail()">SEND</button>
<button>CANCEL</button>
```

In my .ts-

```
export class appComponent{
@Input () emailData: {email:string,confirmEmail:string};
}

    validateEmail(email) {
            var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
            return re.test(email);
        }        
        private sendEmail() {                
            if(this.validateEmail(this.emailData)){        
                this.onEmailSend.emit(this.emailData);
            }
        }
```

When i debug, its stopping the service call when an invalid email is entered but also for valid email address the service call is not happening and hence email is not being sent.Can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Show us the invalid email you are trying to use. Here your regex works fine for my bad email

Comment: I am giving any random data say just  a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please define output param for your component like this:

```
@Output() onEmailSend: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

after that you are able to emit event:

```
this.onEmailSend.emit(this.emailData);
```

then in your parent component you should add this:

```
.
.
.
    onEmailSend(emailData)
    {
        console.log(emailData);
        // something you want to send an email
    }
.
.
.
```

Comment: I was doing all this but thanks for trying.The issue was with the test function where i was passing email.I had to modify that a bit for the exact match.I am marking this answer done though for the effort you put in to help :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<div class="alert-email">
        <label>Email</label>
            <input
                id="email"
                type="text"                
                #email="ngModel"
                [(ngModel)]="model.email"
                required
                pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">

            <div class="md-errors-spacer" [hidden]="email.valid ||    email.untouched">
            <div  *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.required">
                Email is required
            </div>
            <div  *ngIf="email.errors && email.errors.pattern">
                Email is invalid
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and also Angular 2 has a built-in "email" validation tag that can be added within the input

```
<input type="email" id="contact-email" email>
```

Comment: I am doing that already in my HTML. I am just not able to emit the data in case of valid email.

Comment: you have to use angular2 forms to validate form as paramter like this: <form #emailForm="ngForm" (submit)="validateForm(emailForm.valid)"><button type="submit"></form>

Comment: I know :( but i cannot chnage my code at this point of my time.Any way to fix this issue.

Comment: I found whats the problem you did not define the component output "onEmailSend"